# Securely connecting to my DB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Hello all I have a short question. Is this a good and secure way to connect to my DB ?

```
session_start();

$servername = "localhost";
$un = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "project";

$timezone = date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $un, $password, $dbname);

if($con == true) {
}

// Check connection
if ($con->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Comment: The question is rather broad, and doubt it belongs here. As for security, it depends on a lot of parameters like server configuration but on the rest of the code too: if your code is vulnerable to **SQL injections**, then the way you connect to your database is a moot point. There is not much to be said really on a snippet like this.

Comment: This code is not secure as it is disclosing a potentially sensitive infomation contained in the error message to the client. Besides, recently I've answered a broader [question on the mysqli_connect](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243749/101565) at whole that could fit for this question as well

Comment: It is a good idea to store DB auth data in the .env file.

Comment: I'd avoid mysqli in favor of PDO as dealing with objects in PHP will be easier than passing along a connexion handle everywhere you'll need it.

Comment: @Anonymous Breadth of a question is not the problem - most questions of "can this code be improved" are about as broad as it can get; the problem is context. The code must be concrete and presented in the context of the application.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Anonymous that there isn't much to review here.

I would like to point out a few general things.

The db connection credentials are the type of thing that I'd put in a config.php file and include it where necessary.

`$timezone` is probably going to be useless in the longterm.  `date_default_timezone_set()` returns a boolean value to inform you of whether or not you have supplied a valid timezone.  Basically, once this tested once, there is no need to check the return value ever again (until it is changed, of course).

```
$dbCredentials = [
    "localhost", //server name
    "username",
    "password",
    "database"
];

date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

Then just `include` the file and connect by unpacking the indexed array of credentials like this:

```
$con = new mysqli(...$dbCredentials);
```

Notice this is object-oriented syntax.  You should not be mixing styles.

When you are in a development environment (not a production environment), you may return raw error messages. In production, you must never provide raw error messages to users.

When checking for a failed connection, a falsey check (no function call) will be sufficient.  It is vital that you spell your connection variable correctly.

```
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
}
```

That said, an overarching refinement is to perform error handling elsewhere. See [YourCommonSense's advice on error reporting](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/243749/141885).

`session_start();` is usually something that you would put at the top of an include that is run before anything else.

Comment: Man it never occurred to me to use the argument unpacking for the database credentials. A neat solution

Comment: But your attitude towards error reporting is disheartening. Why not just to *set the reporting once* once and then forget about all these manual deaths completely? that's simply less typing and the whole world better practice overall. While nothing would be changed for the OP - their script will die all the same

Comment: Adjusted well enough?

Comment: Look, I never said scripts should never die :) Quite contrary, I am all for the rule "die early and loud". Am a just against manual deaths. What I am trying to say, PHP can die for you on its own will. The topic here is not even the error handling. What I am proposing is just a setting that will make make the connection code die on error without writing die() explicitly. Same outcome, less typing.

Comment: And just as a wonderful side effect, *this code will be error handler-ready* when the OP will be in need for one. So we hit  multiple goals at once: less typing, does exactly the same what it does with manual die() (**but** follows site-wide error reporting settings unlike manual die), and already error handling ready. All thanks to a single error reporting command for mysqli

Comment: What I love Dharman for is that he grasped the idea I  am preaching for so long. A pity I cannot convert you too

Comment: You have been an integral Stack Exchange voice in shaping how I code and advise others.  It is not your fault that I am a slow learner.  It is merely that I haven't **_yet_** aligned all of my advice with your messaging.  This is not deliberate defiance from me -- it's just that the error handling in my day-to-day projects at work are already configured how my employer wants them, so I don't spend any time considering refinements on this portion of code.  (In other words, these are "atrophied coding muscles".)

Comment: @mickmackusa I never said your post was vandalized. I was just informing you of a potential complication.